# Is there equivalent of WPF OriginalSource event property in Winform and ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, winforms

From:

http://www.wpfwiki.com/WPF%20Q14.12.ashx

> The OriginalSource property of the
>   object identifies the original object
>   that received/initiated the event.
>
> Consider a custom control (called
>   CustomControl1 in this example) that
>   is composed of a TextBlock. When a
>   MouseDown event is raised on the
>   TextBlock, the OriginalSource property
>   will be the TextBlock, but in
>   CustomControl1's handler, the Source
>   will be changed to the CustomControl1
>   object so that other elements along
>   the event's route will know that
>   CustomControl1 received a MouseDown.

Is there equivalent of WPF OriginalSource event property in Winform and ASP.NET ? If not how to emulate this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "sender" argument which is sent to the event does not comfort your case, since you need another object to determine the container object which raised the event.

I emulate this by manually firing events either on server-side or on client-side through javascript.

Example:
if a `Span` was inside a `Div`, on the, let's say, click event of the span, I call the click event on its container the div here. And then, in the event handler, the argument will be the div not the span.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks hope MS will improve winform and asp.net as for event routing.